# Rcpp nested loops over lists of vectors of different types: Efficient template solution?

Tags: rcpp

Another interesting Rcpp template programming problem: I want to compute the pairwise complete observations of all columns in an R data.frame or matrix. For matrices the code is easy thanks to [RCPP_RETURN](https://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/rcpp-return-macros/) macros:

```
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

template <int RTYPE>
IntegerMatrix pwNobsmCppImpl(const Matrix<RTYPE>& x) {
  int l = x.nrow(), col = x.ncol();
  auto isnnanT = (RTYPE == REALSXP) ? [](typename Rcpp::traits::storage_type<RTYPE>::type x) { return x == x; } : 
       [](typename Rcpp::traits::storage_type<RTYPE>::type x) { return x != Vector<RTYPE>::get_na(); };
  IntegerMatrix out = no_init_matrix(col, col);
  for(int j = 0; j != col; ++j) {
    ConstMatrixColumn<RTYPE> colj = x( _ , j);
    int nj = std::count_if(colj.begin(), colj.end(), isnnanT);
    out(j, j) = nj;
    for(int k = j+1; k != col; ++k) {
      ConstMatrixColumn<RTYPE> colk = x( _ , k);
      int njk = 0;
      for(int i = l; i--; ) if(isnnanT(colj[i]) && isnnanT(colk[i])) ++njk; // fastest? or save logical vector with colj Non-missing?
      out(j, k) = out(k, j) = njk;
    }
  }
  out.attr("dimnames") = List::create(colnames(x), colnames(x));
  return out;
}

template <>
IntegerMatrix pwNobsmCppImpl(const Matrix<CPLXSXP>& x) {
  stop("Not supported SEXP type!");
}

template <>
IntegerMatrix pwNobsmCppImpl(const Matrix<VECSXP>& x) {
  stop("Not supported SEXP type!");
}

template <>
IntegerMatrix pwNobsmCppImpl(const Matrix<RAWSXP>& x) {
  stop("Not supported SEXP type!");
}

template <>
IntegerMatrix pwNobsmCppImpl(const Matrix<EXPRSXP>& x) {
  stop("Not supported SEXP type!");
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerMatrix pwNobsmCpp(SEXP x){
  RCPP_RETURN_MATRIX(pwNobsmCppImpl, x);
}
```

Now the tricky but comes for data.frames / lists, whose colums can be of different types. It seems to me the native Rcpp solution is a `switch(TYPEOF(x[j]), ...)` statement that handles differently typed columns of a list on a case-by-case basis. Hoever in this case this would require 2 nested switches, leading to an enormous amount of code duplication. I am wondering if this can be avoided through some smart template programming. The basic code for Lists is:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerMatrix pwNobslCpp(const List& x) {
  int l = x.size();
  IntegerMatrix out = no_init_matrix(l, l);
  for(int j = 0; j != l; ++j) {
    int RTYPEj = TYPEOF(x[j]); // The code fails because the SEXPTYPE of x[j] is unknown beforehand!
    auto isnnanTj = (RTYPEj == REALSXP) ? [](typename Rcpp::traits::storage_type<RTYPEj>::type x) { return x == x; } : 
      [](typename Rcpp::traits::storage_type<RTYPEj>::type x) { return x != Vector<RTYPEj>::get_na(); };
    Vector<RTYPEj> colj = x[j];
    int nj = std::count_if(colj.begin(), colj.end(), isnnanTj);
    int rowj = colj.size();
    out(j, j) = nj;
    for(int k = j+1; k != l; ++k) {
      int RTYPEk = TYPEOF(x[k]); // The code fails because the SEXPTYPE of x[k] is unknown beforehand!
      auto isnnanTk = (RTYPEk == REALSXP) ? [](typename Rcpp::traits::storage_type<RTYPEk>::type x) { return x == x; } : 
        [](typename Rcpp::traits::storage_type<RTYPEk>::type x) { return x != Vector<RTYPEk>::get_na(); };
      Vector<RTYPEk> colk = x[k];
      if(colk.size() != rowj) stop("All columns need to have the same length!");
      int njk = 0;
      for(int i = rowj; i--; ) if(isnnanTj(colj[i]) && isnnanTk(colk[i])) ++njk; // fastest? or save logical vector with 
j Non-missing?
      out(j, k) = out(k, j) = njk;
    }
  }
  out.attr("dimnames") = List::create(names(x), names(x));
  return out;
}
```

This code of course fails because the Rcpp templates contained in it are not activated with known values. But templating the whole code does not make sense either because of the pairwise nature of the computation. Is there any way one can do this without the feared nested switch?

Comment: You will always have the compile-time (C++ side, template programming possible) versus run-time (R side, everything is a `SEXP`) conflict when you start from / end with R.  Only the code 'in the middle' not interfacing R can do better.  It's the hand we've been dealt ...